# Gitlab build error - spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2 when updated from java 11 to 17

Tags: gradle, gitlab, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Below is the error I am getting while building the app on gitlab. This build works fine in the local IntelliJ, but when i am tying to build using the CI yml pipeline it fails. I feel in the gitlab the gradle build is using default java version as 11. How can i force gradle to use the java version 17?

My build.gradle has below config -

```
java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
```

```
$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME="$(pwd)/.gradle"
$ export SHORT_COMMIT_SLUG=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" | cut -c1-40 | sed "s/-$//")
$ export NAMESPACE=ns-expansion-$SHORT_COMMIT_SLUG
$ ./gradlew --build-cache assemble
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
.........
..10%............20%...........30%....
........40%............50%...........60%.
...........70%............80%...........
90%............100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Added support for Java 19.
 - Introduced `--rerun` flag for individual task rerun.
 - Improved dependency block for test suites to be strongly typed.
 - Added a pluggable system for Java toolchains provisioning.
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'sample_project'.
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
     Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :
         project :   org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.0.2
        No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 18s
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the older `sourceCompatibility`/`targetCompatibility` configuration, you need to ensure that the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is set to the correct Java installation that is required. In this case for Spring Boot 3, that needs to be a valid Java 17 installation.

Consider adopting/migrating to the more modern solution which is [Toolchains for JVM projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#toolchains).